# Lifting a homeomorphism via an inclusion?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $U\subseteq X$ be a non-empty open subset of a topological space and $f: U\rightarrow Y$ be a homeomorphism.  Denote the inclusion map $i:U\hookrightarrow X$.  When does there exist a topological space $\tilde{X}$ containing $Y$ (denote the inclusion by $j:Y \hookrightarrow \tilde{X}$) and a homeomorphism $G:\tilde{X}\rightarrow X$ such that
$$
i \circ f^{-1} = G \circ j \mbox{ and } G|_{Y}= f^{-1}
?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always. Let $\bar{X}= X \setminus U \cup Y$ where we topologize $\bar{X}$ by saying the map $\bar{X} \rightarrow X$ given by the identity on $\bar{X} \setminus Y$ and $f^{-1}$ on $Y$ is a homeomorphism.

Then this map is by definition a homeomorphism and is easily checked to satisfy your equality.

Comment: Exactly, this follows from the universal property of pushouts in the category Top.